# how to read utf-8 characters from windows console ? Seems that ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() can't handle them

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-8, console, mingw

here is the code that isolate the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  _wsystem(L"echo pure ascii, naïveté");
  COORD pos = {0,0};

  TCHAR* attempt1 = new TCHAR[14];
  DWORD charnum1;
  ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), attempt1, 14, pos, &charnum1);
  wcout << endl << "charnum1: " << charnum1 << ", attempt1: " << attempt1 << endl;
  wcout << "GetLastError: " << GetLastError();

  TCHAR* attempt2 = new TCHAR[16];
  DWORD charnum2;
  ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), attempt2, 16, pos, &charnum2);
  wcout << endl << "charnum2: " << charnum2 << ", attempt2: " << attempt2 << endl;
  wcout << "GetLastError: " << GetLastError();

  system("pause > nul");
}
```

output is:

```
pure ascii, naïveté

charnum1: 14, attempt1: pure ascii, na
GetLastError: 0
charnum2: 0, attempt2: x >
GetLastError: 0
```

First attempt works ok, but when function try to read over position with non-ASCII char then it returns nothing, nor any error is indicated. What to do now ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is compiled with `TCHAR == wchar_t`. You say "nor any error indicated" but 0 is an error indication, per the `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` docs. What does `GetLastError()` return after the failed call?

Comment: I've updated the question with GetLastError call.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: On my system, CP_UTF8 is not available, and so when I run your code the `echo` command results in "The system cannot write to the specified device."

However, if I remove the `SetConsoleOutputCP()` call and leave it at the default codepage, 437, I get the string displayed correctly.

Note, there are separate read and write codepages.  I tried various combinations of 437, 850, 1252, and 28591 -- the latter two more-or-less map to Unicode's first 255 codepoints.
If CP_UTF8 is working for you, re-try your code with a call to `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)`.

Note that `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` does not place a null after the last read character, so you've got a problem in your code when you output that TCHAR array: you have no guarantee it's null-terminated and it could crash.  (Also, you're not deleting your allocated TCHAR arrays.)  So, I changed the allocation lines to this:

```
TCHAR attempt1[] = L"____________________";  // 20 underscores
```

which (with no call to `SetConsoleOutputCP()`) yielded this:

```
charnum1: 14, attempt1: pure ascii, na______
charnum2: 16, attempt2: pure ascii, na∩v____
```

That next-to-last glyph in the second line isn't "n", it's the character 0xEF from codepage 437.  "ï" is character 0xEF from Unicode.  What's happening here is, the correct codepoint (0xEF) was read from the console, but the stream output continues to use the 437 codepage.  Stream output selects its character based on the [locale setting of the stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/imbue/), not the codepage that's been set in the console.

I don't know why the desired codepoint value is read from the console when the console's READ codepage is still 437.  I also am puzzled as to why, if I `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)` (or 28591), the output of the `echo` command looks like it's using CP 437: `pure ascii, na∩vitΘ`